# Python - CSV file empty after rewriting using csv module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm attempting to rewrite specific cells in a csv file using Python.

However, whenever I try to modify an aspect of the csv file, the csv file ends up being emptied (the file contents becomes blank).

Minimal code example:

```
import csv
ReadFile = open("./Resources/File.csv", "rt", encoding = "utf-8-sig")
Reader = csv.reader(ReadFile)
WriteFile = open("./Resources/File.csv", "wt", encoding = "utf-8-sig")
Writer = csv.writer(WriteFile)
for row in Reader:
    row[3] = 4
    Writer.writerow(row)
ReadFile.close()
WriteFile.close()
```

'File.csv' looks like this:

```
1,2,3,FOUR,5
1,2,3,FOUR,5
1,2,3,FOUR,5
1,2,3,FOUR,5
1,2,3,FOUR,5
```

In this example, I'm attempting to change 'FOUR' to '4'.

Upon running this code, the csv file becomes empty instead.

So far, the only other question related to this that I've managed to find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896228/python-csv-file-is-empty-after-using-csv-writer), which does not seem to be dealing with rewriting specific cells in a csv file but instead deals with writing new rows to a csv file.

I'd be very grateful for any help anyone reading this could provide.

Comment: Open the file with `a+` instead.

Comment: @j-darbyshire I've replaced "rt" and "wt" with "a+" and it's still wiping the file. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Set the reader the start of the file.  Directly below the line `ReadFile = open...` add the line `ReadFile.seek(0)`. Now your code should run as expected.

Comment: @j-darbyshire Now the program seems to be keeping the original content and adding the modified content after it. Should I still be using two separate 'open' variables (ReadFile & WriteFile) both using 'a+'?

Comment: I misunderstood your aim. See answer for correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import csv

with open("./Resources/File.csv", "rt", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as ReadFile:
    lines = list(csv.reader(ReadFile))

with open("./Resources/File.csv", "wt", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as WriteFile:
    Writer = csv.writer(WriteFile)
    for line in lines:
        line[3] = 4
        Writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you open a writer with `w` option, it will delete the contents and start writing the file anew. The file is therefore, at the point when you start to read, empty.

Try writing to another file (like FileTemp.csv) and at the end of the program renaming FileTemp.csv to File.csv.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the most logical thing to do in this situation. :)