# Having problems writing to csv

Tags: python, csv

I am taking ticks from the broker and writing it to a csv file. However, when I was reading this csv file sometimes it was printing the right output while sometime the code used to break and the error was about empty dataframe. I decided to check the properties of the csv file while ticks were coming in and I saw that in the middle of the operation the csv file sometimes becomes blank for maybe a sec and then all the ticks are back. I have attached the image of csv file properties, so that you can understand the problem.

This is the function for writing to a csv file :

```
header = ['Date', 'Stock', 'LTP']
data = list()
    def event_handler_quote_update(ticks):
        date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ticks['exchange_time_stamp'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        stock = ticks['instrument'].symbol
        ltp = ticks['ltp']
        data.append([date,stock,ltp])
        
        with open('Ticks.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerows(data)
```

The problem is same if I write to csv from dataframe

```
tick_csv = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Stock', 'LTP'])
tick_csv.to_csv('Ticks.csv', index=False)
```

The ticks file suddenly becomes 0 bytes and then again everything becomes fine.
[Ticks csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x9vo.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896228/python-csv-file-is-empty-after-using-csv-writer I am not sure if this is the same problem, because you are using `with`, but it might help to try.

Comment: When you open the file in `'w'` mode, it overwrites the existing file with new/empty one and then just before you write in it, the size is 0. You can check that the content of the file is just the data you write in a single call of the function. Use `'a'` mode, to append (new file will be created if one does not exists).

Comment: @Larry My files are not empty always, but for a second it becomes empty and then all the tick data is back..

Comment: @buran I also tried this code, but the problem is same: tick_csv = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Stock', 'LTP'])
    tick_csv.to_csv('Ticks.csv', index=False)

Comment: "This code" does not address the problem with mode `w`. The default mode for `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` is again `w`. You need to use `a` (i.e. append).